# What each parameter returned by cuda.get_device_properties represents

Tags: pytorch

_CudaDeviceProperties(name='NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti', major=6, minor=1, total_memory=4095MB, multi_processor_count=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Name of the card: **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti**
- CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: **6.1**
- Total amount of global memory: **4GB**
- Multiprocessors: **6**